# Swift short-circuiting with logical operators not working as expected

Tags: swift, syntax, short-circuiting

```
var anArray = [3, 2, 1]
func sortAndCheck(array: inout [Int]) -> Bool{
    array.sort()
    return array.contains(3)
}

if anArray.contains(3){
    print(anArray) // Prints [3, 2, 1]
}

if anArray.contains(3) && sortAndCheck(array: &anArray){
    print(anArray) // Prints [1, 2, 3]
}
```

For the second if statement, since `anArray.contains(3)` is already true, why does `sortAndCheck(array: &anArray)` still get evaluated and sort anArray?[image]

Comment: With short-circuit execution, your code is equivalent to `if anArray.contains(3) { if sortAndCheck(array: &anArray) { print(anArray) } }`. Since `anArray.contains(3)` evaluates to `true`,  the return value of `sortAndCheck(array: &anArray)` will be evaluated. Assuming that `true && x` is always `true` would be a mistake.

Comment: `&&` can be short-circuited iff left side is `false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short circuiting means that the next part of the expression is not evaluated only if the result is already clear. If the part before `&&` is `true` then the result can still be both `false` and `true` and the next part *has* to be evaluated.

The cases are:

```
1. true && true => true
2. true && false => false
3. false && false => false
4. false && true => false
```

And after evaluating the left operand we have:

```
true && ??
```

which can end either in case 1 or 2, which have different results.

On the other hand, if we had:

```
false && ??
```

Then the result would be either case 3 or 4, which are both `false` and the expression will short-circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The result of an AND (`&&`) boolean operation can only be true if both sides of the `&&` operator are true, so even if the first operand is true, the second one still needs to be evaluated.

Short-circuiting can only happen if you are using a OR operator (`||`) and its first operand evaluates to `true` (resulting in the whole expression evaluating to `true`) or if you are using an AND operator and its first operand evaluates to `false` (resulting in the whole expression evaluating to `false`).

Comment: Shortcut executing takes place in a third case: Optional chaining

Comment: @Carpsen90 you're right, but that's unrelated to boolean operators, which this question was about

Answer (score 2):

> since anArray.contains(3) is already true, why does sortAndCheck(array: &anArray) still get evaluated

Because `X` does not imply `X && Y`. If the expression used `||` instead, then you'd be right, and the second part wouldn't need to be evaluated. But both operands in an AND expression has to be true for the expression to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `&&` operator in `if` statement, `sortAndCheck(array: &anArray)` function should be executed.

If you use `||` operator in `if` statement, `sortAndCheck(array: &anArray)` won't be executed when `anArray.contains(3)` is `true`.